What power compells people to listen to the government and not just say "you know what? No! ;)"?
Do people universally agree on which group of people should govern them and dont change their minds in the matter of seconds? Given that there are so many things people can't agree on and there are so many opinions. Say we have an abstract 1000 humans. Is who their government is decided by what the majority of them think their government is? But governments dont loose their power once the amount of people who aren't satisfied with their policies surpasses that of people who are. Take North Korea as an example.

Welcome to PhilSE! Please read the FAQ and other docs in the help center. This question may be voted to be closed because it's very broad and unfocused. I'd suggest cutting down the question from a wall of words to bite-size Q&A style. Please don't take it personally. :D

You mean the examples? They are just to better illustrate what I mean to avoid ambiguity. Q&A style? That how? You mean I should divide the big one into smaller ones? But they all related, it wouldn't make sence to do that

Any Q&A question with more close to 20 question marks in it is going to be difficult to answer because it's not readily evident which if any explicit questions are rhetorical in nature.

This is kinda more of a metasociological question rather than philosophical, but whatever

I would suggest to find some philosophy article on social contract theory to approach several of those questions, and then ask more refined questions as necessary. And some Bill Bryson if there is enough time to read a lot.

If someone was going to try to answer this question, which I'm not sure is possible, the place to start would be animal social behavior, working your way up the tree, and then noting all the ways in which human behavior departs from that and, as much as possible, why. If nothing else, along the way you will pick up a much richer and more precise technical vocabulary in which to discuss this, such as the difference between hedonic and agonic interactions. (Homo sap seems to be mostly hedonic in small numbers, mostly agonic in large numbers, especially between perceived tribes.)

This seems like too much information for me to process. I am generally not accustomed to reading books. I couldn't read Harry Potter, because I would forget things that I have read a couple of sentences back. The way I am used to learn is by experiencing things and figuring them out, also asking questions.

I recommend reading foundational academic sociologist Emile Durkheim on these issues. Especially his books On Suicide, about how we find meaning in life through social cohesion, & The Elementary Forms of the Religious Life, about how religions should be understood not simply as sets of truth-claims but as psychotechnologies for building & managing social cohesion. Try making notes as you read.

I dont understand what religion has to do with anything of that. What I need is some very precise and detailed real life examples on how things happen down to as small scale as person to person communication. One of the main reasons for why I am even asking this question is the fact that I myself witnessed things factually happening differently from their descriptions in official documents. I suppose its a basic knowledge that people understand intuitively which I due to lack of social experience am missing

This is a pertinent philosophical question but it's surface veneer is not fashionable on this site. Your direction of edits is IMHO not optimal — you don't want to delete large chunks of the question so much as to restructure it away from the rhetorical question format. IOW you should head for ideallty one bold face question in the beginning end or title. And the rest should be more like a "court case" for justifying/elaborating that rather than so chatty

In the new form, it's a trivial question with a trivial answer — What happens to citizens who disobey (the likes of) Stalin, Hitler, Kim?

And why does this happen? I want a complete breakdown of the process. Why doesnt it go like: "kill him" to which some respond "yes" and others like "nah, I dont want to kill that person he didn't do anything wrwrong". Why do the police/gandarms listen to whoever is in charge of them and so on...

I'm not clear whether you're trolling... nah, I dont want to kill that person he didn't do anything wrwrong ¿Seriously? You think that's more likely than If I try to take him put he's going to take me out first? Ultimately your question (in its current form) comes down to Why do people prefer to suffer and live rather than be heroes and die?  This can actually be a profound philosophy question in its own right. But you need articulate it straightforwardly

Yes, seriously. The issue here is that I dont know where to start, because I am missing the piece of a puzzle that I dont even know a shape of. No, its not what you interpreted it to be. I dont know how to form my question properly, but some people will get the point, not you though
